# How to take user input or prompt dialog for user while installing rpm in spec file

Tags: linux, centos7, rpm, rpm-spec

I need to take user-name  and password from user while installing rpm. I have tried to ask user input in %post scriplet but its not working.

Comment: Installation of rpm package should is not interactive and should not require any inputs. Unlike in Debian, configuration and startup of a daemon is not part of rpm installation procedure.

Answer (score 2):

RPM installation is not interactive. So, you won't be able to read input from the user during RPM installation.

But if you do want to provide input during RPM installation, you can write username and password in a file say "/tmp/credentials.txt" and read this file during RPM install.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found it myself . You can use like this and it worked fine.....

```
echo "**********Please enter password**********">/dev/tty
if exec </dev/tty; then
    read -s pwd
fi
%global password $pwd
```